# Co-Simulation: AnyLogic and Unreal Engine

Tags: simulation, anylogic, unreal-engine5, fmi

I understand that AnyLogic has a 3D Engine to visualize simulations, as described in the [AnyLogic Documentation](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/3d/index.html). Since the [Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US) is one of the most powerful 3D engine, I was wondering if it would be possible to [couple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-simulation) these two tools, maybe using an [FMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_Mock-up_Interface). Therefore, my question is, how one could iteratively 1.) calculate a timestep in AnyLogic, 2.) visualize the results in Unreal.

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: The answer is yes. But that is not your real question, is it? ;) If you want to know how, check the AL conference from 2019, there was a talk by an oil company doing this, maybe that points you in the right direction. And do report back, this is of interest to a lot of folks :)

Comment: I assume you are referring to [this talk](https://www.anylogic.de/upload/conference/2019/presentations/transocean-drilling-rig-digital-twin-and-virtual-well-construction-simulation.pdf), held on the [AnyLogic Conference 2019](https://www.anylogic.de/resources/conference/alc-2019/#program). Unfortunately, it does not explain, how they did it.

Comment: No, but now you know whom to reach out to :). When you find out, you report back here :D